# Chrome extension - XMLHttpRequest - net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to make a chrome extension that uses ratemyprofessor with my university's courses. I am trying to retrieve the results based off of searching for a specific professor's name from ratemyprofessor. My code is like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', searchURL, false);
xhr.send();
```

I get the 'net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE' error from doing this. Is there a better way of retrieving data from another website in Javascript? I am pretty new to this, so I don't really know. The purpose of this request is to see how many professor's names came up from the query, and if there is only one professor, I can link to him or her.

Comment: Is your `searchURL` using `https` protocol ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am thinking this problem is due to the fact that I am accessing a different domain?

Comment: Can you paste the `searchURL` you are using ? I think `ratemyprofessor` they just don't support `https` connection.

Comment: var searchURL = 'https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=HEADER&queryBy=teacherName&schoolName=University+of+mySchool+&schoolID=someID&query=' + lastName; // last name is last name of teacher